# Image is in ul navigation bar

Tags: html, video, styles

I am kinda new to the programming and i am making a school project,
i made an "ul navigation bar" step by step from w3schools and then i tried to put a video in the page, but video kinda messed up my navigation bar, any ideas how to make the bottom of the navigation bar fixed so when I put img or video it won't do this? Thank you!

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='cs'>
  <head>
    <style>
    body {margin:0;}
h1 {
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
li {
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}    
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #7092be;
  position: sticky;
  top: 75px;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  float: left;
}
li {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #496fa0;
  }
.active {
  background-color: #bdcce1;
}

.center { margin: 0width: 480px; }
</style>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='description' content=''>
    <meta name='keywords' content=''>
    <meta name='author' content=''>
    <meta name='robots' content='all'>

  </head>
    <body>
    <h1> Vtipy na den</h1>
     <ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Domov</a></li>
  <li><a href="ctyri.html">Najdu co neznám</a></li>
  <li><a href="obrazky.html">Obrázky</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="videjko.html">Video vtip</a></li>
  <li><a href="tabulky.html">Tabulky</a></li>


     <div>   
        <video class='center' width="640" height="480" controls autoplay>
  <source src="vtip1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="vtip1.mp4" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

here is the page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/35sSc.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't closed your `ul` tag after the last `</li>`

Answer (score 0):

I've neatened your code for you and fixed the issue. You'd just forgot to close your `ul` tag, you need to close tags for a new block level element to display unless you've decide for it to use `display flex`, you can also give your DIVs names and create a new DIV for each section of the page to force a block level element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}

li {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #7092be;
  position: sticky;
  top: 75px;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #496fa0;
}

.active {
  background-color: #bdcce1;
}

.center {
  margin: 0width: 480px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='cs'>

<head>

    <title>Page title</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='description' content=''>
    <meta name='keywords' content=''>
    <meta name='author' content=''>
    <meta name='robots' content='all'>

</head>

<body>
    <h1> Vtipy na den</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Domov</a></li>
        <li><a href="ctyri.html">Najdu co neznám</a></li>
        <li><a href="obrazky.html">Obrázky</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="videjko.html">Video vtip</a></li>
        <li><a href="tabulky.html">Tabulky</a></li>
    </ul>
        <div>
            <video class='center' width="640" height="480" controls autoplay>
                <source src="vtip1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="vtip1.mp4" type="video/ogg"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was so obvious and yet i did not notice it, sometimes i feel really dumb.
Thank you!